# igrep mode incovenient compilation of results

Tags: search, emacs, lisp

I am using igrep.el package and liking it.
There is one thing that bothers me though.
In the igrep results page, the first and last lines are highlighted as part of the compilation and so cycling through the results using next-error will eventually hit these two lines with no corresponding files of course.

These are the format of these first and last files:

```
Igrep started at Thu Aug  1 15:15:23

finished (matches found) at Thu Aug  1 15:15:27
```

I believe that this is the code responsible for these lines to show up all together.
How to disable these lines from showing in the grep results or at least not having them highlighted as part of the results:

```
(if igrep-find
(setq command
      (igrep-format-find-command command files)))
(cond ((eq igrep-save-buffers t) (save-some-buffers t))
  (igrep-save-buffers (save-some-buffers)))
(if (fboundp 'compilation-start)    ; Emacs 22
    (let ((compilation-process-setup-function 'grep-process-setup))
      (or (fboundp 'igrep-mode)
          (define-derived-mode igrep-mode grep-mode "Igrep"))
      (compilation-start command
                         'igrep-mode
                         nil
                         (cond ((eq compilation-highlight-regexp t))
                               (compilation-highlight-regexp
                                (if (eq program "fgrep")
                                    (regexp-quote regex)
                                  regex)))))
  (compile-internal command (format "No more %s matches" program)
                    "Igrep" nil grep-regexp-alist))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that regular expressions for those lines expects a "Grep", instead of "Igrep".  As a quick hack, you may replace the two "Igrep" strings of that piece of code by "Grep".

A less hacky solution would be to add to `grep-mode-font-lock-keywords` the expressions for those regexps.  It will be easy: just look at the current value of that var and duplicate regexps starting by "^Grep" to similar ones starting by "^Igrep"

Comment: Yup that fixed it...I am thankful to you.
I did change  'igrep-mode to 'grep-mode and that fixed it.